# How does the concept of Live server works?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, networking, server

lets say in visual studio I'm giving open with live server and start to work with my html, css and js.

When I save then in browser the changes which I made is immediately uploaded automatically, when I have live server extension.

Also I have seen this in angular framework. What is the concept behind this, like I want to know in depth like if involves http methods packets and all the networking stuffs??

This is the extension which I'm talking about:

[image: This is the extension which I'm talking about]

Answer (score 3):

Static files located on your computer like HTML, CSS and JS don't need a server to be opened by your browser. What your extension does is just reloading your browser when it detect changes in your static files. In this sense,  it doesn't involve networking.

Angular kind of works the same except that it need to create a bundle with all your files (transpiling typescript, etc.) and serve them via a server with the `ng serve` command. The use of a server and networking for Angular is motivated by the fact that ajax request and redirecting is made hard in local static files, for security reasons.

If you were to use PHP, Node or any server side language for your project, you will need a server that will run code upon requests and this will involve networking.

By the way, static files (HTML, CSS and JS) are often served through server. But this will not involve any server side logic. this means every requests will get the same static files.

Comment: wow its that simple?? I thought it may involve any complex concept. thanks for your answer

Comment: To develop a bit more, you can see in the FAQ of your extension a small paragraph about this common misconception https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension#the-common-misconception

If my answer helped you, you could mark it as accepted ;)